# The Euler's method problem but with repaired method

Tags: calculus

Consider the change of $\Delta y$ in solution between $x_0$ and $x_1$. One approximation obtained from Euler's method: $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{y(x_1)-y_0}{h} \approx \frac{\hat{y}_1 - y_0}{h} \approx f(x_0,y_0)$.

Here, $\hat{y}_1$ shows the Euler's approximation to the solution in $y_1$. Another approximation obtained through the approximation search to the solution's slope in $x_1$.

$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{y(x_1 - y_0)}{h} \approx f(x_1,y_1) \approx f(x_1,\hat{y}_1)$

Note: I found this question in one of the Calculus book (Varberg, Rigdon, Purcell, Volume 1), page 356.

Now, I want to applied this for equation $y'= y, y(0) = 1$ with $h = 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.005$ to approximate the solution of interval [0,1] (Note that the exact solution is $y=e^x$, such that $y(1) = e$. The question calculate the error in approximation $y(0) = 1$.

But the problem is I can't find the errors for the approximation $y(1) = e$ with $h = 0.1$ and $h = 0.005$. I tried to figure it out and find the answer, but I can't find a single clue.

Comment: Yeah. It's very complicated. I even used that to compare the errors between Euler's method and this repaired one. But, I couldn't find it. Do you have some clue for this problem?

Comment: Parameter $h$ in these methods is often referred to as the step size.  Starting from $y(0) = 1$, the given initial value, the exercise expects you to "march" toward an approximation of the solution at $y(1)$.  Smaller step sizes will of course mean more steps (and more calculation), but with prospect of getting better accuracy.  The "error in approximation" is presumably the (absolute value of the) difference between $y(1) = e$ , the exact solution, and the approximate value obtained by marching.